# Cannot batch a Dataset after it has been windowed?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Batching windows of a `Dataset` results in an error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.data.Dataset.range(7).window(3, 2, 1, True).batch(2)
# NotImplementedError: Batching for `tf.data.Dataset` objects.
```

Why is that? What would be a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this exact code in Google Colab, it works for TF1.15.rc and TF2.0, but not for 1.14.0 or lower. It seems like a bug, maybe you can raise an issue on Github.

Comment: Strange. I have tried both on Windows and Ubuntu with TF 1.14 and I get the error I reported.

Comment: Mmh, if this is fixed in TF 1.15 then I don't see the need to file an issue, although I don't see something related to this problem in the release notes.

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggested raising an issue.